# Проверочные слова: синица,воробей,снегирь

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, есть ли проверочные слова для "**воробей, синица, снегирь**"? Как их проверить?

Comment: А как, curator, проверяли до сих пор?

Answer (score 3):

Начнем со **снегиря**. Проверочное слово - *снег*. Подтверждается этимологией: по Фасмеру, *снегирь* буквально значит 'снежный' (кстати у него в словаре пишется *сн**И**гирь*).

**Синица** проверяется словом *синий*, что также подтверждается этимологией (по Фасмеру, *синица* связано с *синий*).

Со словом **воробей** картина несколько иная. В современном русском языке первую гласную *О* проверить нельзя. Вторая *О* проверяется словом *вор**о**бушек*. Этимология в данном случае лишь подтверждает, что нужно запомнить буквосочетание -оро-. Народная этимология от "вора бей" (проверочное слово *вор*) здесь абсолютно не соответствует действительности. Ну, разве что только помогает запомнить правописание первой гласной :-)

Answer (score 1):

СИНИЦА. Общеслав. Соврем. синица < зиница, суф. производного от зинь. В таком случае, птица получила свое название сначала по характерным для нее звукам, а затем — по цвету оперения.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, считается. что синица - слово звукоподражательное (от зинь - воспроизведение чириканья птички), а народная этимология сблизила название с синим цветом (информация из словаря Шанского).

В то же время названия птиц по цвету действительно существуют, например: соловей - от "соловый" (желтоватой масти), сойка - от "синий" (о.-с. корень si -  синий, сизый, сиять).
Так что вопрос о происхождении "синицы" не полностью ясен (в словаре Черных указывается, что название соответствует оперению).

Также интересно, что западные славяне называют синичку иначе - sikora, от  sik - шипеть. В русском языке слово очень давнее, встречается в  словаре Даниила Заточника (XII или XIII в.).

Answer (score 0):

[@olsa](/users/246/olsa), только сейчас обнаружил. Ну какая же синица синяя?! Серая спинка, желто-зеленое брюшко, коричневая "шапочка"... ;) ну никак нельзя её синим "проверять".

Comment: Я не придумываю :-)) И у Фасмера, и у Цыганенок эта версия озвучена.

Comment: Можно «переехать» с этим в комментарии?

Comment: Нельзя. )) Три года тут никому не мешало, а теперь вдруг переехать?! И как вы себе это представляете технически?