# Происхождение слова "филин"

Tags: этимология

Птица филин, интересно происхождение названия. Не могу найти нигде. Воробей ворует, поползень ползает, синица синяя и тд. А "филин" вообще ни о чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От общеславянского – kviliti - "визжать", "реветь", "ухать" и проч.; "звукоподражательное".
О квилить очень много еcть:

*kviliti (sf()/*kvjleti: болг. цвuля ржать (о лошади)' (РВЕ; Геров,
Дювернуа: цвuЛt7!), таRже диал. цвuлu (М. Младенов БД 111, 187;
Д. Евстатиева. с. Тръстеник, Плевенско. - БД VI, 237), цви,А,е-м
ГPOMKO плакать; ржать (о лошади)' (Стойчев БД 11, 298), макед.
цвuлu ('скулить, повизгивать' (И-С), сербохорв. kviliti (визжаr;rь
(о поросенке)' (RJA У, 855; РСА IX, 406: диал. 1'tвuлumu), cvf/eti
(плакать, Rричать, визжать' (RJA 1, 869-871), также cmi/eti
(RJA 1,818), словен. cviliti скулить, визжать; свистеть (о ветре);
плакать, стенать' (Plet. 1, 91), чеш. kviliti, kvileti жаловаться,
причитать', слвц. kvilit' жаловаться, громко плакать' (88] 1,
804), диал. kevelic э'е прихварывать' (Диалект., Братислава;
Buffa. Dlha Luka 163), н.-луж. стар. (Якубица) kwilis pыдaTЬ,
вопить, оплакивать' (Muka 81. 1, 763), также cwilis (там же),
полаб. kvaile 3 л. ед. наст. XHЫKaTЬ, плакать' (Polanski-8ehnert,
86, с реконструкцией *kvili), СТ.-ПОЛЬСR. kwilic кричать, издавать
голос (о птице); плакать, жаловаться; раздражать' (81.
stpol. 111, 478; 81. polszcz. XVI W., XI, 623; Лексикон 1670 r.,
 л. 92: Kwil(!'sif). Плачю), польск. kwilic, kwielic плакать, хныкать',
(стар.) доводить до слез' (Warsz. 11, 666), диал. kwilic (sif?) (81.
gw. р. 11, 545), словин. kvjllec скулить' (Lorentz 810vinz. Wb. 1,
536), kvilёс (8ychta VII. 8uplement 115), др.-русск., русск.-цслав.
цeUJl,Umu (плакать' (Гр. Наз. ХI в.), (печально петь' (Прол. XV В.)
(Срезневский&III 1436), русск. диал. "видить, "ведить (драЗНИТЬ1
сердить, обижать (обычно о детях)' (яросл., костр., волог., новг.,
орл., тамб., куйб., оренб., казан., перм. и др.), XHЫKaTЬ, плакать'
(яросл., перм., тобол., тюмен.) (Филин 13, 167; Сл. русск.
гов. Новосиб. обл. 218), говорить человеку неприятно ти' (Элиасов
154), 1'tuJtumb (ворчать, жаловаться' (волог., свердл.), (неотступно
просить' (волоr.) (Филин 13, 208), 1'tидиться (просить,
молить о чем-либо' (арх., онеж.), плакаться, жаловаться' (арх.,
онеж., волоr.), (сердиться' (свердл.) (Филин 13, 208), уКр. 1tBUдити
плакать, стонать; кричать, преииущественноlжалобно
(о зверях, птицах)' (Гринченко 11, 232).
Вариант к* kvё.liti (см.). Звукоподражательногопроисхождения.

(Фасмер)

~~~~
И если уж говорить о воробьях, то ***синица** - тоже никакая не синяя*, вы вообще видели её? Скорее всего развилось из звукоподражательного цинь-цинь. Об этом же свидетельствует и народное название синицы - зинзивер.
Как бы еще и спополжнем та же история не приключилась. Что-то сомневаюсь я, что он "ползает". ))))

Comment: Поползень - птица, которая может ползать по стволу дерева вниз головой. Что там с этимологией - не проверяла, но то, что поползень "ползает", правда. О синице у Фасмера - от "синий", у Цыганенко две версии: от "синий" или от звукоподражания *zinь.

Comment: Ну значит и тут дурит авторитет. ))) ну никогда я не соглашусь, что синицу (не лазоревку, не малиновку, даже не того же поползня) могли назвать синей. Конечно значение синий несколько изменилось, раньше оно пошире было, но не настолько же. И конечно, близкие народные названия никакн не "синие".  

Поползень не ползает, он прыгает по стволу дерева во всех напрявлениях. Не знаю, кому пришло в голову назвать это движение ползаньем.

Comment: **behemothus**, +1 за Ваш ответ.
Отмечу только, что у Вас в цитате по-видимому, опечатка. (Может быть, так отсканировано?)

> уКр. 1tBUдити плакать, стонать;
> кричать, преииущественноlжалобно (о
> зверях, птицах)' (Гринченко 11, 232).

На укр., так же как и на старославянском,  
**КВИЛИТИ -- стонать (жалобно); плакать; кричать (жалобно)**  
[Источник][1]


  [1]: http://hohlopedia.org.ua/ukrajinsko_rosiyskyy_slovnyk/search/?word=%CA%C2%C8%CB%C8%D2%C8

Comment: ;-)) Поползень, видимо, совершает поползновения, т.е. попытки (шутка)

Comment: >Отмечу только, что у Вас в цитате по-видимому, опечатка   

Да я даже не читал. Фасмера вообще невозможно без опечаток сканировать, там же огромное число специальных знаков. Только картинкой.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то слово **воробей** не связано с глаголом **воровать** :-)) [Смотри здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8C)

Что касается слова **филин**, то, по мнению Фасмера, все существующие этимологии недостоверны. Тем не менее приведу здесь данные словаря Цыганенко. В рус. словарях отме- 
чается с XVIII в. Развилось, вероятно, из стар. *квилинъ* «филин», «стонущая птица» вследствие изменения **кв** в **хв** > ф (ср. *фасоль* и соответствующее 
укр. *квасоля*). Сущ. *квилинъ* образовано, полагают, с помощью предметного суф. 
-ин- (как *блин*) от глаг. *квилити* «стонать» или (как *воин*) от утрач. *квиль* 
«стон» звукоподражательного происхождения. Глаг. квилити соответствует др.- рус. *цвилити* «плакать», в котором **цв** из **кв** (ср. цветок — укр. квітка). Эта версия была высказана Далем. Ее же придерживается в своем словаре П.Я.Черных. Сам Фасмер полагает, что слово **филин** может быть сокращением имени собств. Филимон из греч. Φιλήμων. Версия еще менее правдоподобная :-)))

Теперь о происхождении слова **воробей**. Здесь тоже не все просто. Фасмер полагает, что оно родственно греческому ρόβιλλος, а также литовскому žvírblis "воробей", и приходит к заключению, что корень *virb - это звукопожражание, связанное с семантикой 'звенеть, звонить'. Лично мне кажется сомнительным, чтобы для птицы, которая всегда рядом с человеком, а никакая не перелетная, название славяне заимствовали из греческого :-))
Цыганенко выдвигает версию, что **воробей** - древн. славянское слово. Соврем. его форма развилась из др.-рус. *воробии* «воробей» вследствие изменения **ии** в **ей**. Др.-рус. *воробии* возникло из праслав. *vorbьjь «ворсбей». В нем -or- между согласными изменилось в полногласное сочетание -оро-, а суф. -bj-ь (-ij-ь) — в **ии**. Ср. также ст.-сл. *врабии*; польск. wrobel, где 1 вместо j; чеш. vrabec «воробей». Праслав. *vorbьjь образовано с суф. -bj-ь (-ij-ь), как в слове *соловей*, от звукоподражания 
*vorb-. Ср. от этого же звукоподражательного корня, однако с полногласием -оро- и заменой нач. звука **в** на **г**, образовано с суф. -ец-ь укр. слово горобець «воробей». 
В итоге, как вы можете видеть, оба исследователя сходятся в мнении, что слово воробей  образовано от звукоподражательного корня *virb (или *vorb), но это никак не связано с воровством.

Comment: Фасмер явно ерундит. Этимология Ф<КВ вполне себе достоверная.

Comment: И на старуху бывает проруха :-))

Comment: Мне встречались такие фамилии, как Оробей, Оробец.  
Это что-то более позднее, диалектное? Как вы думаете? 

Или, может быть, наоборот, слово-предшественник, из которого уже развилось рус. "воробей" и укр. "горобець" ?

Comment: Это фрнетические варианты. Осемь-восемь, острый-вострый и проч. Отсюда и "оробей". Хотя возможно и какое-то совсем другое происхождение.  
Оробец - это из украинского. Г могло пропасть как фонетически чуждое русскому.